# ExtJS 5 xtype datefield is not working when selecting month or year

Tags: extjs, datefield

When clicking on the dropdown to select individual months/years the dialog disappears like I am trying to click away.

fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/9m6

```
   Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Simple Form',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        width: 350,
        // The fields
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Start Date',
            id: 'startDate'
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    });
```

This has been fixed in ExtJs 5.1.0.107

> EXTJS-15968 Date Picker disappear after click on Month Picker.
>
> http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/whats_new/release_notes.html

Comment: Please add the essential parts of your code. If the link you provided become broken, the code will not be available.

Comment: Seems really weird, you should file a bug with Sencha. Here's an even smaller reproduction https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/amr `Ext.widget({xtype: 'datefield', renderTo: Ext.getBody()});`

Comment: As a workaround, you can use `ctrl+left/right` to switch months, and `ctrl+up/down` to switch years

Comment: works fine in examples and api docs : http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#form-date

Comment: @Dawesi presumably because the Examples and Api Docs don't use renderTo. If renderTo is unsupported as of 5.0.1, it would be nice if one would find that in the docs. So, definitely a bug.

Comment: Reported this behavior to Sencha http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?292913-ExtJS-5-xtype-datefield-is-not-working-when-selecting-month-or-year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug indeed in Ext.Js v 5.0.1.
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289825

Solution with overriding Ext.picker.Date class worked for me:

```
Ext.define('EXTJS-14607.picker.Date', {
    override: 'Ext.picker.Date',


    runAnimation: function(isHide) {
        var me = this,
            picker = this.monthPicker,
            options = {
                duration: 200,
                callback: function() {
                    picker.setVisible(!isHide);
                    // See showMonthPicker
                    picker.ownerCmp = isHide ? null : me;
                }
            };


        if (isHide) {
            picker.el.slideOut('t', options);
        } else {
            picker.el.slideIn('t', options);
        }
    },


    hideMonthPicker: function(animate) {
        var me = this,
            picker = me.monthPicker;


        if (picker && picker.isVisible()) {
            if (me.shouldAnimate(animate)) {
                me.runAnimation(true);
            } else {
                picker.hide();
                // See showMonthPicker
                picker.ownerCmp = null;
            }
        }
        return me;
    },


    showMonthPicker: function(animate) {
        var me = this,
            el = me.el,
            picker;


        if (me.rendered && !me.disabled) {
            picker = me.createMonthPicker();
            if (!picker.isVisible()) {
                picker.setValue(me.getActive());
                picker.setSize(el.getSize());
                picker.setPosition(-el.getBorderWidth('l'), -el.getBorderWidth('t'));
                if (me.shouldAnimate(animate)) {
                    me.runAnimation(false);
                } else {
                    picker.show();
                    // We need to set the ownerCmp so that owns() can correctly
                    // match up the component hierarchy, however when positioning the picker
                    // we don't want it to position like a normal floater because we render it to 
                    // month picker element itself.
                    picker.ownerCmp = me;
                }
            }
        }
        return me;
    }
});
```

Comment: This overiding works on 4.2.3 also. Thanks a lot @Aleksei