# Month field on EXTJS 5.1: cannot select march, october or december if Ext.Date.monthNames is redefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

After having found [this site](http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=28167452&ttl=EXTJS+5+-+Date+picker+year+and+month+only) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197217/month-field-on-extjs-5-1) I made [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1aaa). If `Ext.Date.monthNames` is defined (for german translation) it is not possible to select march, october or december... The actual month is selected instead (may for example today). If it is not defined, it is possible to select those months... Amazing...

Does someone have any suggestion?
(tested on Chromium 50.0... 64bit)

Comment: It appears that the problem is solved with the latest version of ExtJS (6.0.2)... But I use version 5.1 GPL and 6.0.2 has no GPL release

Comment: I have tried to reproduce in your fiddle (ExtJS 5.1.0), and managed to select März 2016. I just had to doubleclick "Mär" and "März 2016" was written in the box. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the solution to this problem. You are not overriding the [monthNumbers](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Date-property-monthNumbers) property of `Ext.Date` object. So in order to change the months name to German months names do this:

```
Ext.Date.monthNames = ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'];

Ext.Date.monthNumbers = {Januar: 0, Jan: 0, Februar: 1, Feb: 1, März: 2, Mär: 2, April: 3, Apr: 3, Mai: 4, Mai: 4 , Juni: 5, Jun: 5, Juli: 6, Jul: 6, August: 7, Aug: 7, September: 8, Sep: 8, Oktober: 9, Okt: 9, November: 10, Nov: 10, Dezember: 11, Dez: 11};
```

And that's it, your fiddle will be working as intended(I have tested it).

This [sencha forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?157025-Ext.Date-monthNames-monthNumbers-getMonthNumber) link could be useful.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing need to add month name the default name already here
[sencha doc](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/modern/Ext.Date.html#property-monthNames)